# Test application mobile on local server

Tags: apache, mobile, apache2, mobile-safari

I have a simple question,I started to develop a mobile application using PHP on my local machine,I use Ubuntu and apache2 server,the question is how I test my mobile template on my laptop like I see it on line on a mobile (iphone,...),for simple page we use firefox or IE Browser but for mobile temple the dimensions is different.How devellopers of mobile application do to test it locally.

OS : Ubuntu 11.10 , server : apache2 , IDE : netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,there is a list of emulators here: http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators